# how to resize windows ec2 root volume (c)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

is there an automated way to resize a windows ec2 instance root volume (c)?

1. expand the root volume by 10GB
2. extend the disk within the OS

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/automating-amazon-ebs-volume-resizing-with-aws-step-functions-and-aws-systems-manager/

Comment: but im not using cloudwatch to monitor space. we dont want to use that because of costs

Comment: the point is you need a parameter or a metric to monitor your space, then only your automation will be invoked, how does your automation logic will get to know that your are on low disk space?

Comment: i want to invoke the disk expansion manually. but manually meaning, when we get notified of low disk space on C drive. I can run a script on expanding that volume and also extend it in the guestos

Comment: added a solution, if it helped you an acceptance would be appreciated, so that it helps in the future

Answer (score 0):

There is no ideal way to do that without cloud watch metrics irrespective of ec2 or windows.

Yes, a crude way can be to utilize the windows command line `du` tool and run a cron job with it. and store the disk info in a file.
Run grep on the file, if low disk space message is there, run your script